# Obtener datos de una datatable con SQL en C# vía código

Tags: c#, sql

Estoy comenzando con C# (Solo 2 semanas con él). Se me presenta una duda con relación a la pregunta. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using VisorRpt.Models;


namespace VisorRpt.Reportes
{
    public partial class Visor : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        DataTable dt;
        OleDbDataAdapter da;

        private string Txt;
        private string XSel;
        private string oradb = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=UMBD;User Id=DESAUMBRELLA;Password=USERDESA;";
        public static OleDbConnection Conn;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool Rsl;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            Rsl = Conectar();
            if (Rsl)
            {
                Txt = "SELECT * FROM M_TIPO_REPORTE WHERE TIPO_REP_ID=182";
                da = new OleDbDataAdapter(Txt,Conn);
                dt = new DataTable();
               **// Sitio del error
                da.Fill(dt);
                XSel = dt.Rows[0]["SQL_T_REP"];
                // hasta aquí.**
            }

        }
        public bool Conectar()
        {
            OleDbConnection Conn= new OleDbConnection(oradb);
            try
            {
                Conn.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

En el Fill me da el error:

```
*Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.InvalidOperationException' en System.Data.dll pero no se controló en el código del usuario
Información adicional: Fill: la propiedad SelectCommand.Connection no se ha texto destacado inicializado.*
```

Y no veo cuál es el problema.

Comment: tu conexion esta bien ?

Answer (score 0):

Hermano prueba asi, lo que te falta es definir que es procedure, query.

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Your Connection string");

Conn.Open;

DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("your select query");

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd.Connection = conn;

using (OracleDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter())
{
  dataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
  dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
}
```

Comment: Pierro, te agradezco mucho y ya tengo solucionado el problema, el que tengo ahora es que el reporte que quiero no se presenta, todo funciona pero cuando coloco ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh(); no presenta sino la página web sin mostrar la data, podrías ayudarme allí, caso dado mi correo es maximiliano.gil@gmail.com

Comment: @MaximilianoGilToro claro

Comment: @MaximilianoGilToro te mande un correo para ayudarte